# Posting an image on Tumblr using OAuth

Tags: objective-c, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to post an image on Tumblr using OAuth. I'm using Objective C, but a general solution would be very helpful as well.

I manage to post an image that is online (using the "source" parameter). However, I can't post an image from the client (using the "data" parameter), and some issues confuse me.

1) Should I use "multipart/form-data" or "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"? I've seen conflicting claims on this issue.

2) What should I put in my post body and what should I put in my basestring? According to the oAuth specifications, if I use  "multipart/form-data" then I don't need to add the parameters that I add to the post body (like "type" and "caption") to the base string, but even when I succeeded posting with "source", it only worked if I added the parameters to the base string as well.

3) In what format should I add the image to the body? If I need to also add it to the base string, then in what format should I add it there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Tumblr is "unusual" implementation of OAuth ([OAuth issues](https://github.com/nquinlan/Tumblr-OAuth/issues/2)). It's not likely to be possible with "old" OAuth (from code.google.com/p/oauth/). I myself ended up using one of these solutions: [crossbreeding OAuth with ASIFormDataRequest](http://hytgbn.net/2012/02/tip-of-uploading-images-to-tumblr-using-oauth-on-ios/), but it is not likely to work with multiple images, or integrating [TumblrUploadr](https://github.com/vvanhee/TumblrUploadr). Also, Tumblr is likely to work better with new OAuth library (from [here](https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer))
, but it will definitely conflict with ShareKit if you use it.

Concerning your questions:

1. TumblrUploadr uses *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* so it
   is likely to be this one.
2. With any of solutions above, you should
   just pass UIImageJPEGRepresentation of your image. TumblrUploadr has
   it's own URL-encoding and for ASIFormDataRequest, I'm not sure.
3. URL-encoded binary data, as it is said in Tumblr API. I myself
   didn't investigate ASIFormDataRequest deeply, so I'm not sure if you
   need to add it to base string.